# convert special characters like % and $ to double in java

Tags: java, double, special-characters

I have a String which contains special characters like '$' and '%'. When I am converting String to double using `Double.parseDouble()` method, String part is getting converted fine, but $ or % is overlooked by method. I want '$' or '%' to be post fixed with output.What can I do?

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
double dm;
String st = "12.27%"
double fn = getDoubleValue(st, dm);
System.out.println("final value of double " + fn);
}
double getDoubleValue(String st, double dValueForNull) {
        if (st == null || st.trim().length() <1)
        return dValueForNull;
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(st);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            return dValueForNull;
        }
    }
```

Output: final value of double 12.27
I would like to postfix % with the output. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can't put those symbols in a double.

Comment: I know, but is there a way by which I can put those symbols in output without converting the output in String??

Comment: It is hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve or what is your use case, but consider this `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(st.substring(0, st.length() - 1)) + "" + st.charAt(st.length() - 1));`

Comment: Sergei Sirik, I just want to add those symbols as suffix to the double output generated by Double.parseDouble() method..the solution provided above works fine for % symbol. But it doesnt work for $ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try DecimalFormat. There's an example in the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html